# How to fix Overflow Data table-outside the content box?

Tags: html, view, datatable

I am having some datatables in different pages. In few pages tables looks fine, In some pages, it exceeds the `<div>` and overflows on the page. How to fix it?

Code below:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 datagrid">
    <table
      style="width: 100%;"
      id="table"
      class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd"
    >
      <thead>
        <tr class="gridheader">
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 1</td>
          <td style="width: 20%;">Data 2</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 3</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 4</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 5</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 6</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 7</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 8</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 9</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 10</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 11</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 12</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Image of table working fine:**

[image]

**Image of table overflow the page:**

[image]

Same code used for both pages, Why does this overflow? Even horizontal scroll bar also not shown, and it somehow looks like table went outside the box and it spoils the design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are facing this issue because the column width that you have provided is not sufficient for both column name and the sorting option to accommodate on in a single line, so to avoid such issue you can make your datatables responsive.

You can read more about this in below link

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/

Comment: sir ur one fixed my issue, but not the responsive one, as u mentioned that column name and sorting option is the main issue for this , I removed sorting option for all column except data 1, now its working fine for me..` { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": [  1, 2, 3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11 ] }` .I added this inside my datatable script.that works for me. As ur ans gives me the solution path, I tick it as right answer

Answer (score 1):

If you are going to have lot of `<tr>` inside a `<td>` it is better for you to add overflow-x:auto.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 datagrid" style="overflow-x:auto;">
    <table  id="table"  class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered table-hd" >
      <thead>
        <tr class="gridheader">
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 1</td>
          <td style="width: 20%;">Data 2</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 3</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 4</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 5</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 6</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 7</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 8</td>
          <td style="width: 10%;">Data 9</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 10</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 11</td>
          <td style="width: 5%;">Data 12</td>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sir ur one created the horizontal scroll bar for me. But Is there any other way to fix it within the page, as my design not looks fine,I am asking dis...

Comment: @Riya I did this since i took mobile in consideration too. When you have this much table the table will not enlarge in mobile view and the font will reduce as there are lots of tr tags hence it is better to use scroll rather than making the table width 100vw.

Comment: sir, thank u for ur help, but removing the sorting makes my table fix within the page. Still I give upvotes for ur timely help sis.. Thank u sir

Comment: @Riya never mention :)